# Excel Cell remains in edit mode after activating other Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

En Excel/VBA, when double clicking a cell in Worksheet A, I want to display a userform, and then activate a Worksheet B.
This works, however whenever I edit any cell in worksheet B, the cells in Worksheet A still get the inputs.

In worksheet "A":

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    UserForm1.Show
    End sub
```

UserForm cancel button:

```
Private Sub CancelButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Hide
    Worksheets("B").Activate
End Sub
```

In sheet A, excel opens a userform, I click on Cancel, it goes indeed to sheet B. But whatever I type in B, goes into A.
As workaround I need to manually go to A, and then go to B again.
How can I avoid this woraround ? 
The same issue occurs with the BeforeRightClicking event and seems to be due to the fact the activate is done through a userform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems okay. Activate any cell on `Sheet(B)` which will ensure editing cells in `Sheet (B)`. Use `Range("A1").Activate` or any cell.

```
Private Sub CancelButton1_Click()
    Worksheets("B").Activate
    Range("A1").Activate
    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Also use `UserForm1.Hide` code at the end of other codes.

Comment: Userforms take the focus by default, and the flow of logic: however, the converse is true when the form is 'Modal'  - the flow of logic follows the focus -  and I suspect that the `UserForm1.Hide` command is acting as an 'Exit Sub', which means that @Laurent's `Worksheets("B").Activate` statement is never executed.

Comment: Try a MsgBox with a test message after the 'Hide', followed by `Worksheets("B").Activate`... Then try it with the form set to non-modal. Your code works, and it's perfectly  good code, but you can improve your answer by explaining why Laurent's initial attempts didn't work, and yours did...

Comment: Thats why I suggested to use `UserForm1.Hide` code and the end of sub.